# How to make Horizontal Scroll Effect work on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrolltrigger

I have a horizontal Scroll Effect where when the user scrolls down, the page goes to the side. This works fine on my computer, but when I try to use it on a smaller device, it doesn't work

Example Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75krURg63fM

Here is my Code:
HTML:

```
<div class="info">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.slide:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.slide:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: lightcoral;
}


.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 300vw;
}
```

JS:

```
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const tl = gsap.timeline();

tl.to(".wrapper", 10, {x:-window.innerWidth})
.from (".slide", 1, {})

.to(".wrapper", 10, {x:-window.innerWidth*2})
.from (".slide", 1, {})


ScrollTrigger.create({
    animation: tl, 
    trigger: ".wrapper",
    start: "center center",
    end: "+=4000",
    scrub: true, 
    pin:true 
})
```

Please tell me if there are any errors and what I can do to fix my problem